# Exclude phrase ending with matched pattern using regex

Tags: regex

I have written a rule to catch all web domains ending with `.watch` or `.video`, and I want to exclude 2 domains:

`(?!\.videolecture|fb\.watch)\b(\.video|\.watch)`

The first exclusion `.videolecture` works fine. But I can't exclude `fb.watch`.

I'm really sorry but I could't find any similar questions on stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
\b(\.video(?!lecture\b)|(?<!\bfb)\.watch)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f4iACy/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(` - start of a capturing group:

  - `\.video(?!lecture\b)` - `.video` that is not immediately followed by `lecture` as a whole word
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<!\bfb)\.watch` - `.watch` that is not immediately preceded with `fb` as a whole word
- `)` - end of the group.

Answer (score 0):

An exclude variable could be set using a map. To exclude second-level domains, *videolecture* or *fb*, and top-level domains, *watch* or *video*:

```
map $host $exclude {
    ~\b(?:videolecture|fb)\.(?:watch|video)$ 1;
}
```

Return 403 if `$exclude` is set:

```
server {
    if ($exclude) {
        return 403
    }
}
```